# NodeJS: Best way to send mass texts at specific time based on MongoDB entry?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am writing a application which needs to send text messages based on MongoDB database entries using AWS. I am saving the message, phone number and the time to send the message in the database and I can currently send a text using the number and message. I am trying to figure out the best way to send the messages at the appropriate times. I was originally thinking the best way to do it would be to have a cron job that queries the database every minute and then sends the text. However would cron jobs be suitable for doing this reliably and at scale? Also if the database gets too large would it take too long to query each minute? I also considered using the setInterval to run a query every minute. But both of these ways seams like if it were to take longer then a minute to query the db it would be trying to query it twice and potentially send duplicate messages or cause other problems. Is one of these a good way to handle this situation or would something else be better?

Comment: regarding database efficiency you may use 'indexes', it will help to process your query faster.

Comment: if data is really too much that it is taking too much of time then don't take all the data once in a minute, you can brake it in sections by using limits. for example if you are fetching 1000 docs in min and it is taking time, then make a sequential process for fetching 100 docs at a time. make another req to DB for another 100 docs just in the callback of previous query. If this also become less for your data then you need to think for scaling (either node app or DB whichever is responsible for slowness).

Answer (score 0):

1. Setup a cron job that runs every minute which queries : ((locked:not_exists || locked: false) && record.time_to_send <= current_time)
2. Now in cron job keep a flag 'locked' which is set as true whenever a record is about to be processed (or sending message)

You might also want to have a look at AWS lambda or step functions.